# How can I increase an existing account size?

Tags: anchor, account, space, constraints

ie. Initialize account with 255 byte space. Pay to double the space through anchor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in Anchor with `realloc*` constraints.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Example {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"example"],
        bump,
        realloc = 8 + std::mem::size_of::() + 100,
        realloc::payer = payer,
        realloc::zero = false,
    )]
    pub acc: Account<'info, MyType>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

You can find more info in [this table](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html) in the docs.

Alternatively, you can use Solana's [`realloc`](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html#method.realloc) method, which is used by that constraint ☝️ under the hood.

```
my_account_info.realloc(255, false);
```