# Best way to keep track of all the PDAs that has been created by my program in Solana

Tags: pda

Let's say I have something like Twitter, where a post can be liked/unliked, and you can see all the people that have liked the post.

Coming from Solidity, we can easily do this with an `address[]` that inserts the user's address if they like or removes if they unlike.

With Solana, I've learnt that we should use PDA for this case, and I think it can work to a certain extend (user knows if they like or dislike a post), but for the "query all users that like this post" requirement, I have not found the solution. To know it, we need to keep track of all the PDAs that have been created, but afaik Solana's `Vec<PubKey>` cannot have dynamic size (or in other words it can only contains a fixed number of `PubKey`). Unfortunately with that limitation it won't work for this case.

What should I do in this case? I'm pretty lost. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: If possible, I also want to query this kind of data on-chain (in my program).

Answer (score 5):

You can use getProgramAccounts with filters. Here's Solana cookbook reference: https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#filters

Here's an excellent blog specifically focused on querying tweets from a Solana program that replicates Twitter: [https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch/fetching-tweets-from-the-program](https://Fetching%20tweets%20from%20the%20program)

The basic idea is that you use the `memcmp` filter (standing for memory comparison) to compare certain data fields stored in accounts. The filter would depend on how you have structured your accounts and program. For example if I have a user account and a tweet account in my program. And I want to fetch all tweets by a particular user, I can do something like:

```
const data = await program.account.tweetAccount.all([
  {
    memcmp: {
      offset: 8,
      bytes: anchor.utils.bytes.bs58.encode([5138]),
    },
  },
  {
    memcmp: {
      offset: 8 + 4 // memory size of the `owner` or similar field,
      bytes: new anchor.web3.PublicKey("user_pub_key").toBase58(),
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that there's way to query the data off-chain (though the filter is very limited). What I'm wondering is if there is a way to query this data directly from the program, that part is hard.

Comment: Oh okay. My bad, I didn't know you meant to say querying in program itself. Yeah that is a bit tricky.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I have to change the requirements a bit to make it work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to get the complete list of all users that liked the post on-chain, you might need to store all the pubkeys in a single account(i.e a `likes(Vec<Pubkey>)` field) and extend the account size if needed. You might need to keep track of the current capacity of the `likes` vector, or else calculate it dynamically from the account data's size whenever you need it. This is because `Vec::capacity` will always just return the size of the deserialized vector, essentially `Vec::len`.

Hence you'd just have to check for when `capacity == length` and then extend the account using the steps shown [here](https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-change-account-size).

An alternate way to keep track of the capacity is to always fill up uninitialized keys in `likes` with `Pubkey::default` so `Vec::capacity` gives the actual capacity. You'd then find and replace a default pubkey to insert an actual one, and know the capacity is filled up when there's no default to replace.

You can also just extend the account's size by 32 bytes for each like and make the user pay for their space. This would mean you don't need to track capacity as it's always used up.

P.S: I'm skeptical that you would need this information on-chain though. For most cases, the canonical way to handle stuff like this would be to use pdas, retrieve all pdas using the `getProgramAccounts` call on the client side, and only validate those accounts in your on-chain code(you might consider a merkle or hash-chain solution, but this might be expensive wrt compute). Do you mind sharing your use-case in this scenario?

**EDIT**:
Based on additional context provided, it seems like what you'd need is a pda for each user that tracks how much SOL they purchased, and a shared pda for all users that tracks how much SOL has been purchased in total. Then you wouldn't need to always store and update the equivalent token amount, as how much tokens a user is entitled do be dynamically calculated during the claim/distribution step using the information outlined above.

If there's multiple rounds of claim/distribution, you should also consider adjusting your program to take previously claimed tokens into account in your calculations to prevent a double-allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think increasing the data size would work as there is a size limit (10MB iirc) so it'll run out eventually. 

My dApp is a presale contract, which allows users to purchase my token with SOL. The part I'm struggling with is I need to modify the amount of token an user receives based on how much OTHER users purchase. For example:

- User A and B both purchase 50 SOL, which amounts to 50 tokens;
- User C purchases 200 SOL, crossing a threshold of 100 SOL. The excessive SOL will be distributed to all users below that threshold (in this case A and B).

Comment: So with that requirements I need to keep track of A, B, C, along with their purchases. And that's just 3 users, imagine there's a lot of users involved which cannot be estimated.

Comment: There's more to it but hopefully you get why I need to access this information on-chain. I've been searching around but it looks like this use case is not very popular on Solana.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't understand your answer well, as I thought the 10MB max size only applies to the regular account, not PDA. Now that I got it, I think it's a very solid idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds interesting! I'll update my answer to take into account the additional context you've just provided. If you don't mind, can you also do the same for your question?(Kindly indicate that it's an edit).

Answer (score 2):

You actually can resize accounts.

[How can I increase an existing account size?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-can-i-increase-an-existing-account-size)

Solana uses a `Vec<(String, String)>` for the `additional_metadata` of the TokenMetadata token22 token-metadata interface.

Link to the code:
[solana token-metadata interface additional_metadata github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/93b0969b678c92063e819a12558fcdd18f64c409/token-metadata/interface/src/state.rs#L39)

It is recommended to put a dynamic sized data at the end of the account struct so any other data can be easily filtered, because once you get to vector data you have to do more work for filtering since the size will be dynamic.

I don't know how your `Post` account data looks, but including a vector of dynamic data every time you fetch a post doesn't feel like a great way to handle this. Instead I would add a couple more accounts `PostLikes` and `PostDislikes` which will be PDA's derived with `['post-likes', post.key()]`. The likes and dislikes can be a counter stored in the post so you can still quickly get the amount of likes and dislikes without needing to get all of the pubkeys of the likers/dislikers. Then inside of `PostLikes` and `PostDislikes` you can have the `Vec<Pubkey>`.

Now if you want to get the number of likes/dislikes, just get the post data. If you want to get the pubkeys of the likes/dislikes, use the post to get the pda for the `PostLikes`/`PostDislikes` account.

Keep in mind account size and rent costs. A Pubkey is 32 bytes. 100,000 likes would be at least 3,200,000 bytes which is about 22 sol at current rent prices, which could be paid for and expanded by you as needed, or paid for by the user when they like the post.

**Edit**: Also note that accounts actually do have a max limit still. So if you really need 100,000 all in one account to be checked on-chain, you won't be able to use a PDA.
If you don't need them all in one account, you can chunk them up and still use PDA's as well as another account keeping track of which chunk a likers/dislikers Pubkey is in. Just brainstorming here though, as it really comes down to what exactly you are trying to do.

At the time of this writing:

- Accounts have a max size of 10MB (10 Mega Bytes)
- PDA accounts have a max size of 10KB (10 Kilo Bytes)

[solana cookbook account facts](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/accounts.html#facts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The idea of making a separate PDA just to store the `Vec<Pubkey>` is very nice. Come to think of it, I was under the assumption that a PDA size could only be 4KB max. If it can be up to 10MB, the PDA can hold over 300k `Pubkey`, so will be more than enough for my use case. Thanks again, I will try implementing it and see how it goes.